# Need acces from document to collection Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to do an iOS app and i've binded it with firebase, so I'm trying to get some posts ad fetch them, and this works fine, however this posts got 2 collections (likes and replies) and i'm trying to fetch likes, the thing is that I can't get the likes because for some reasons I can't a class for document forEach neither I can't access it, someone got any idea?

Code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Post : Hashable {
    var id : String
    var dateAdded : String
    var posterEmail : String
    var posterUsername : String
    var posterIcon : String
    var postTitle : String
    var postBody : String
    var likes : [String]
    var userLikedPost : Bool
}

struct Like {
    var likeId : String
    var likerEmail : String
}

class Likes {
    var likes : [Like] = []
    
    func fetchLikes() {
        //Firestore.firestore()
    }
}


class Posts : ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts : [Post] = []
    
    func fetchPosts() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").getDocuments(completion: { (docPosts, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("error fetching posts")
            } else {
                docPosts?.documents.forEach { (post) in
                    let id = post.documentID
                    let email = post.get("posterEmail") as! String
                    let username = post.get("posterUsername") as! String
                    let icon = post.get("posterIcon") as! String
                    let title = post.get("title") as! String
                    let body = post.get("body") as! String

                    // Here i want to insert the code that gets the likes class and access the likes variable
                    
                    self.posts.append(Post(id: id, dateAdded:String(id.split(separator: "_").joined(separator: "/").prefix(10)) ,posterEmail: email, posterUsername: username, posterIcon: icon, postTitle: title, postBody: body,
                                           likes: [],userLikedPost: false))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague and the code presented in the question doesn't line up with what's you're trying to do. The Post->likes property in an *array of strings* `var likes : [String]` which will not be directly related to the `Like`struct  or `Likes` class. Are you trying to read that array of strings or do you want to initialize objects with the string data or.... ? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I just want to read the likes and show how many there are.

Comment: We don't know what 'likes' you're trying to read as Firestore isn't aware of a Likes class. Do you mean you just want to read the array of strings that are stored in Firestore?

Comment: I've got a collection names posts where are different documents, the respectively posts, inside posts there is a collection, named likes, that's what i'm trying to get

Comment: But that's not what's in the question, nor is it part of your `Post` structure. Your `Post` structure contains an array of strings `var likes : [String]` If that's what you want to get, I can add an answer, if it's something else, please clarify the question, the structure and what you're attempting to do.

Comment: The Post likes is for swiftUi when i iterate throug then so yeah I want to get the likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore structure was not included in the question so I will present one for use

```
user_wines
   uid_0
      name: "Jay"
      favorite_wines:
         0: "Insignia"
         1: "Scavino Bricco Barolo"
         2: "Lynch Bages"
   uid_1
      name: "Cindy"
      favorite_wines
         0: "Palermo"
         1: "Mercury Head"
         2: "Scarecrow"
```

And then the code to read all of the user documents, get the name, the wine list (as an array as Strings) and output it to console

```
func readArrayOfStrings() {
    let usersCollection = self.db.collection("user_wines")
    usersCollection.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in

        guard let allDocs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in allDocs {
            let name = doc.get("name") as? String ?? "No Name"
            let wines = doc.get("favorite_wines") as? [String] ?? []
            wines.forEach { print("   ", $0) }
        }

    })
}
```

and the output

```
Jay
   Insignia
   Scavino Bricco Barolo
   Lynch Bages
Cindy
   Palermo
   Mercury Head
   Scarecrow
```

*EDIT*

Here's the same code using Codable

```
class UserWineClass: Codable {
   @DocumentID var id: String?
   var name: String
   var favorite_wines: [String]
}
```

and the code to read data into the class

```
for doc in allDocs {
    do {
        let userWine = try doc.data(as: UserWineClass.self)
        print(userWine.name)
        userWine.favorite_wines.forEach { print("   ", $0) }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it, i just get the wrong structure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for including the Codable example, Jay. This is the recommended way for mapping Firestore documents from / to Swift.